# c# calculate overlaps between arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, overlap

i'm not looking for a straight answer, instead some type of guidance. If you are going to post the straight up code would you please explain it all as i'm wanting to learn as much as i can.

I'm trying to calculate and output the overlaps between two arrays. Here is my code so far.

```
 class Tester
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Box[] boxArray1 = {
                                new Box(4, 3, 2, "white"),
                                new Box(9, 5, 6, "red"),
                                new Box(3, 6, 12, "purple"),
                                new Box(15, 10, 4, "orange"),
                                new Box(4, 14, 10, "black"),
                          };

        Box[] boxArray2 = {
                                new Box(3, 4, 2, "pink"),
                                new Box(10, 2, 4, "red"),
                                new Box(8, 5, 7, "white"),
                                new Box(14, 4, 10, "blue"),
                                new Box(10, 15, 4, "bindle"),
                          };


    }//end of static main
    static void calculate1(Box[] box1) // <== Here's my attempt at calculating the overlaps.
    {
        string[] name = box1[i].Split(' ');
        int gr1 = box1.Length;
        int[] gg1 = new int[gr1];
        for (int i = 0; i < box1.Length; i++)
        {
            gg1[i] = int.Parse(box1[i]);
        }
    }

}//end of class Tester
class Container
{
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public Container(string co)
    {
        Colour = co;
    }
    public virtual string GetContainerType()
    {
        return "Unknown";
    }
}//end of class Container

class Box : Container
{
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }

    public Box(double Le, double He, double Wi, string co)
        : base(co)
    {
        Length = Le;
        Height = He;
        Width = Wi;
    }
    public override string GetContainerType()
    {
        return "Box";
    }
    public double GetVolume()
    {
        return Length * Height * Width;
    }


}//end of class Box
```

As shown at the top, there are the dimensions of the box along with the colors. I am wanting to find the overlaps between these two arrays, such as "White", and "Red", are shown in both arrays. Then i am wanting to calculate and then output "There are 2 Box objects with overlapping colors between the two arrays.", then do the same for the Dimensions.

Thanks.

Comment: does this compile  `string[] name = box1[i].Split(' ');`? doubt it does. `i` is not declared by that time, and `Box`  doesn't have a `Split` method(atleast within the code provided anyway)?

Comment: By "overlap" you mean the boxes intersect among them? If that's the case then use `Rectangle.IntersectsWith`

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Yeah it doesn't compile. I was just messing around with previous to code to see if it works. And yes, that's all my code. At this point i have no idea what it could be so i'm just trying random stuff

Comment: @Gusman I'm not drawing anything though? - it's just random values I had put into the arrays.

Comment: @John.555 Rectangle struct does not draw anything, is just an struct representing a rectangle in arbitrary coordinates, if you store the limits of your boxes instead of in plain variables inside a Rectangle then you can use the IntersectsWith function which it has.

Comment: @John.555 hmmm, I see you have width, height and length, is this a 3D box representation? If that's the case then it's a lot more complex, you will need something like the SAT algorithm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219904/separating-axis-test-for-axis-aligned-bounding-box-and-triangle-produces-incorre

http://www.dyn4j.org/2010/01/sat/

Comment: @Gusman Here's the error i got when I tried that, I did it within the static main at the top: `Error 1 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'IntersectsWith' and no extension method 'IntersectsWith' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) `

Comment: @John.555 you must iterate each element on A and intersect with each element on B.

Comment: @Gusman im very new at this, i think you might be looking a bit too deep into this haha. All i am wanting to do is compare the two arrays and count the overlaps

Comment: @John.555 define "overlap"

Comment: @Gusman The color white and red are in boxArray1, **and** boxArray2. So i'm wanting to write the code to gather that information then output it in a console.writeline as "There are 2 Box objects with overlapping colors between the two arrays.". Then I am wanting to do the same for dimensions, even though they are all different.

Comment: @John.555 oook, so you don't care about the sizes, only whant to check if there are boxes with same colors in both arrays?

Comment: @Gusman I am wanting to do the exact same thing to the sizes as well, but yes im wanting to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to the last comment in your question, to check it create a double loop and check for the properties:

```
List<string> duplicatedColors = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < boxArray1.Length; i++) //Loop through the first array
{
    for (int j= 0; j < boxArray2.Length; j++) //Loop through the second array
    {
        if(boxArray1[i].Color == boxArray2[j].Color) //Do element at array 1 have the same color that the item at array 2?
        {
            //Yes, store color and break inner loop
            duplicatedColors.Add(boxArray1[i].Color);
            break;
        }

        //No, continue loop
    }
} 

//Here now you have all the duplicated colors in duplicatedColors
//You can use duplicatedColors.Count to get the number of items dupicated.
```

Ok, now for the volumes:

```
List<double> duplicatedVolumes = new List<double>();

for (int i = 0; i < boxArray1.Length; i++) //Loop through the first array
{
    for (int j= 0; j < boxArray2.Length; j++) //Loop through the second array
    {

        var volumeA = boxArray1[i].Length * boxArray1[i].Width * boxArray1[i].Height; //Compute box A volume
        var volumeB = boxArray2[j].Length * boxArray2[j].Width * boxArray2[j].Height; //Compute box B volume

        if(volumeA - double.Epsilon < volumeB && volumeA + double.Epsilon > volumeB)
        {
          //Check if the volumes are equal, note the use of the Epsilon, that's because 
          //double values aren't exact and we must have that into account. double.Epsilon 
          //is the smallest (not lowest) value a double can store so it's very 
          //thightened, you can increase this value if you have errors.

            duplicatedVolumes.Add(volumeA);
            break;
        }

        //No, continue loop
    }
}
```

Comment: This does go within the static main right? -- I get an abundance of errors shown here:  http://i.imgur.com/1Uao6iW.jpg

Comment: Sorry, updated the answer, not sure why I wrote the int specifier outside the for declaration...

Comment: Awesome! thank you that worked for color :), i just had to write it all out then it worked. Would it be the similar thing for the volume of the boxes? There are 3 overlaps that i've noticed for the volume which are "4, 3, 2", "15, 10, 4", and "14, 4, 10", since they all equal the same thing when calculating the volume

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand you completely. As the boxes exists on coordinate 0,0,0 (you haven't defined any position) any box with dimensions bigger than 0 will overlap any other box with non-zero dimensions. If you want to check if there is a box with the exact same length, width and height then add to the if's these properties, something like this: `if(boxArray1[i].Color == boxArray2[j].Color && boxArray1[i].Length == boxArray2[j].Length && boxArray1[i].Width== boxArray2[j].Width && boxArray1[i].Height == boxArray2[j].Height)`. If not one of these two cases better explain the real purpose

Comment: That seems to give me an output of 0. I think this will better explain it. Those 3 volumes I mentioned above, they are in each array. The result of those volumes are the same. Such as, 4*3*2 is the same as 3*4*2 in boxArray2. Since the result of those equations are the same, that adds to the total count of duplicatedVolume.

Comment: Ok!!! So you want to check if you have a box with the same volume and color, is that right?

Comment: I'm not looking for if 3 is in the same column within the second array. I'm after the total equation result being the same

Comment: Thats correct!, but i'm wanting color and volume to be in separate iterations

Comment: Ok, check it now, read very carefully the comments about Epsilon.

Comment: Awesome! that worked :) thank you heaps. That Epsilon part, is that needed? - when I ran it I got an output of 0. So i changed `if(volumeA - double.Epsilon < volumeB && volumeA + double.Epsilon > volumeB)`, to `if (volumeA == volumeB)` and it outputted '3' which is correct.

Comment: It should, but maybe using `double.Epsilon` changes the number to `NaN`. instead of `double.Epsilon` use `0.000001` or any value as small as you need, else if you use decimals in your sizes it will fail at some point as double is not 100% precisse and has a bit of error, you need to give it a bit of tolerance.

Comment: As an example, `0.0345 * 1.34` is not the same as `0.00345 * 13.4`, it should be but the results are different, you can check it by yourself, one yields `0.046230000000000007` and the other `0.04623`.